# How does power remain constant when powering devices at different voltages?

Tags: dc, ohms-law

As per the below image, increasing the voltage in a circuit with just a resistor results in an increase of current and therefore power.
However if I have a circuit where I am just powering a DC device (say a Wifi Router) which can operate on 12-24VDC, the higher the voltage supplied within that range, the lower the resulting current.

I know the power is staying constant so mathematically it makes sense. It also intuitively makes sense - the router only needs a maximum of 12W to operate, therefore the higher the voltage supplied, the lower the current that is required to generate the energy needed to power the router.

What I don't understand is *what* is this router doing to reduce the current at higher voltages? Why isn't it acting like a resistor?

Thanks

edit: fixed diagram, thanks user253751

[image: Comparison of Resistor Circuit vs Powering a DC Device]

Comment: This is an example of negative resistance, (increasing voltage causes reduced current) many DC-DC converters behave like this.

Comment: Actually the power in circuit 3 is 48W, not 24W

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The explanation for the scenario you are presenting is that the Wifi router has a switchmode DC-DC converter (likely a [Buck Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter)) inside which converts the input voltage of 12-24V into a fixed voltage needed by the other circuitry inside. DC-DC converters have the property that Pout = Pin * eff where Pout is the output power of the converter, Pin is the input power of the converter, and eff is the efficiency of the converter. For switchmode DC-DC converters typical efficiency is 80 percent or more, and only varies slightly with input voltage. For example it might be 82 percent at Vin = 12V and 78 percent at Vin = 24V. I just made up those numbers but they are kind of typical.

The input power is probably not perfectly constant. It is probably a little bit higher at 24 V than it is at 12V because the efficiency is probably a bit lower (if it is a buck converter, which it probably is).

Answer (score 2):

Other have given great explanations but I'm gonna drop it down a notch in case it is helpful.

Somewhere inside the router a capacitor is being charged and kept at a certain voltage level. The capacitor will charge faster with higher input voltages and slower at lower input voltages. There is feedback circuitry to control the width of the pulses charging that capacitor.  The capacitor is also being discharged at a somewhat but not quite contestant rate by the function of the router. The feed back circuitry balances the charge rate and the discharge rate of the capacitor by controlling the charging pulse width to keep the capacitor at the desired voltage.